# Constants from class instance ruby

Tags: ruby, constants

I have some class instances and need to get constants from them. As example:

```
class MyClass
    CONST = 1
end

my_class = MyClass.new
my_class.CONST => undefined method `CONST' for #<MyClass:0x0000000234ca68>
my_class::CONST => #<MyClass:0x00000002ba75a0> is not a class/module
```

I know that examples like this will work fine:

```
my_class.class::CONST
MyClass::CONST
```

Does ruby have some simple methods for getting constants from class instances?

Comment: Why can't you get constants from the class itself?

Comment: What is wrong with `my_class.class::CONST`? Are you expecting anything simpler than that?

Comment: I have method wich return me instance of some class. And beside constants, I need methods from them. So `.class` don't work for me.

Comment: What do you mean by needing methods?  Are you talking about accessing class methods from an instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the class to the module. And the method does not return an instance of the class, and the name of the module! Of course it will work if you have the opportunity to static methods, which in my case I can not afford. And how to do it without the module, I don't know.